# Overleaf correctly compiled document fails for Arxiv

Tags: overleaf, arxiv

I have a latex paper which I want to publish on Arxiv. It compiles correctly on Overleaf. After that, I export it for Arxiv via the Submit button. But it fails when I import it in Arxiv, showing the following error message:

```
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \sf@counterlist

l.95 \begin{document}

?
! Emergency stop.
<argument> \sf@counterlist
```

I cannot find out what this error message is telling me and could not find a hint by googling. Could you please help me understanding the error message, what the bug is and what I can do to fix it?
I can also provide you with more information if necessary.

**UPDATE:**
I have update the document and shorten it, so I can show the content here:

```
% Last Version 30-03-2020
% \pdfoutput=1
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
% \addbibresource{AnomalyDetection.bib}  

\usepackage{arxiv}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}

\newcommand{\citea}[1]{\citeauthor{#1} \cite{#1}}
\newcommand{\citepa}[1]{(\citeauthor{#1} \cite{#1})}

\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}
\numberwithin{Definition}{section}



\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

%\title{Anomaly detection of univariate timeseries: A comparison of statistical vs classical machine learning vs deep learning approaches}
\title{Anomaly Detection}

\author{MB}




\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection Anomaly detection \citea{Chandola2009}
\end{abstract}




\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{AnomalyDetection.bib}
\end{document}
```

Uploading this document from Overleaf to Arxiv results in the same error:

```
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \sf@counterlist

l.73 \begin{document}

?
! Emergency stop.
<argument> \sf@counterlist

l.73 \begin{document}

No pages of output.
Transcript written on AnomalyDetection.log.
```

**UPDATE 2:** Here the `arxiv.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\ProcessOptions\relax

% fonts
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}

% set page geometry
\usepackage[verbose=true,letterpaper]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \newgeometry{
    textheight=9in,
    textwidth=6.5in,
    top=1in,
    headheight=14pt,
    headsep=25pt,
    footskip=30pt
  }
}

\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\flushbottom
\sloppy

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyheadoffset{0pt}
\rhead{\scshape \today}
\cfoot{\thepage}


%Handling Keywords
\def\keywordname{{\bfseries \emph Keywords}}%
\def\keywords#1{\par\addvspace\medskipamount{\rightskip=0pt plus1cm
\def\and{\ifhmode\unskip\nobreak\fi\ $\cdot$
}\noindent\keywordname\enspace\ignorespaces#1\par}}

% font sizes with reduced leading
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{%
  \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xipt
  \abovedisplayskip      7\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 5\p@
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus 3\p@
  \belowdisplayskip      \abovedisplayskip
  \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus 3\p@ \@minus 3\p@
}
\normalsize
\renewcommand{\small}{%
  \@setfontsize\small\@ixpt\@xpt
  \abovedisplayskip      6\p@ \@plus 1.5\p@ \@minus 4\p@
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@  \@plus 2\p@
  \belowdisplayskip      \abovedisplayskip
  \belowdisplayshortskip 3\p@ \@plus 2\p@   \@minus 2\p@
}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\@setfontsize\footnotesize\@ixpt\@xpt}
\renewcommand{\scriptsize}{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viipt\@viiipt}
\renewcommand{\tiny}{\@setfontsize\tiny\@vipt\@viipt}
\renewcommand{\large}{\@setfontsize\large\@xiipt{14}}
\renewcommand{\Large}{\@setfontsize\Large\@xivpt{16}}
\renewcommand{\LARGE}{\@setfontsize\LARGE\@xviipt{20}}
\renewcommand{\huge}{\@setfontsize\huge\@xxpt{23}}
\renewcommand{\Huge}{\@setfontsize\Huge\@xxvpt{28}}

% sections with less space
\providecommand{\section}{}
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
                {-2.0ex \@plus -0.5ex \@minus -0.2ex}%
                { 1.5ex \@plus  0.3ex \@minus  0.2ex}%
                {\large\bf\raggedright}%
}
\providecommand{\subsection}{}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                {-1.8ex \@plus -0.5ex \@minus -0.2ex}%
                { 0.8ex \@plus  0.2ex}%
                {\normalsize\bf\raggedright}%
}
\providecommand{\subsubsection}{}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                {-1.5ex \@plus -0.5ex \@minus -0.2ex}%
                { 0.5ex \@plus  0.2ex}%
                {\normalsize\bf\raggedright}%
}
\providecommand{\paragraph}{}
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                {1.5ex \@plus 0.5ex \@minus 0.2ex}%
                {-1em}%
                {\normalsize\bf}%
}
\providecommand{\subparagraph}{}
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}{%
  \@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}%
                {1.5ex \@plus 0.5ex \@minus 0.2ex}%
                {-1em}%
                {\normalsize\bf}%
}
\providecommand{\subsubsubsection}{}
\renewcommand{\subsubsubsection}{%
  \vskip5pt{\noindent\normalsize\rm\raggedright}%
}

% float placement
\renewcommand{\topfraction      }{0.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction   }{0.4}
\renewcommand{\textfraction     }{0.1}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.7}

\newlength{\@abovecaptionskip}\setlength{\@abovecaptionskip}{7\p@}
\newlength{\@belowcaptionskip}\setlength{\@belowcaptionskip}{\z@}

\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{\@abovecaptionskip}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\@belowcaptionskip}

% swap above/belowcaptionskip lengths for tables
\renewenvironment{table}
  {\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{\@belowcaptionskip}%
   \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\@abovecaptionskip}%
   \@float{table}}
  {\end@float}

% footnote formatting
\setlength{\footnotesep }{6.65\p@}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{9\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\kern-3\p@ \hrule width 12pc \kern 2.6\p@}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}

% paragraph formatting
\setlength{\parindent}{\z@}
\setlength{\parskip  }{5.5\p@}

% list formatting
\setlength{\topsep       }{4\p@ \@plus 1\p@   \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength{\partopsep    }{1\p@ \@plus 0.5\p@ \@minus 0.5\p@}
\setlength{\itemsep      }{2\p@ \@plus 1\p@   \@minus 0.5\p@}
\setlength{\parsep       }{2\p@ \@plus 1\p@   \@minus 0.5\p@}
\setlength{\leftmargin   }{3pc}
\setlength{\leftmargini  }{\leftmargin}
\setlength{\leftmarginii }{2em}
\setlength{\leftmarginiii}{1.5em}
\setlength{\leftmarginiv }{1.0em}
\setlength{\leftmarginv  }{0.5em}
\def\@listi  {\leftmargin\leftmargini}
\def\@listii {\leftmargin\leftmarginii
              \labelwidth\leftmarginii
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
              \topsep  2\p@ \@plus 1\p@    \@minus 0.5\p@
              \parsep  1\p@ \@plus 0.5\p@ \@minus 0.5\p@
              \itemsep \parsep}
\def\@listiii{\leftmargin\leftmarginiii
              \labelwidth\leftmarginiii
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
              \topsep    1\p@ \@plus 0.5\p@ \@minus 0.5\p@
              \parsep    \z@
              \partopsep 0.5\p@ \@plus 0\p@ \@minus 0.5\p@
              \itemsep \topsep}
\def\@listiv {\leftmargin\leftmarginiv
              \labelwidth\leftmarginiv
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listv  {\leftmargin\leftmarginv
              \labelwidth\leftmarginv
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listvi {\leftmargin\leftmarginvi
              \labelwidth\leftmarginvi
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}

% create title
\providecommand{\maketitle}{}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \par
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
    % for perfect author name centering
    \renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\hbox to \z@{$^{\@thefnmark}$\hss}}
    % The footnote-mark was overlapping the footnote-text,
    % added the following to fix this problem               (MK)
    \long\def\@makefntext##1{%
      \parindent 1em\noindent
      \hbox to 1.8em{\hss $\m@th ^{\@thefnmark}$}##1
    }
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \@maketitle
    \@thanks
    %\@notice
  \endgroup
  \let\maketitle\relax
  \let\thanks\relax
}

% rules for title box at top of first page
\newcommand{\@toptitlebar}{
  \hrule height 2\p@
  \vskip 0.25in
  \vskip -\parskip%
}
\newcommand{\@bottomtitlebar}{
  \vskip 0.29in
  \vskip -\parskip
  \hrule height 2\p@
  \vskip 0.09in%
}

% create title (includes both anonymized and non-anonymized versions)
\providecommand{\@maketitle}{}
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \vbox{%
    \hsize\textwidth
    \linewidth\hsize
    \vskip 0.1in
    \@toptitlebar
    \centering
    {\LARGE\sc \@title\par}
    \@bottomtitlebar
    \textsc{}\\
    \vskip 0.1in
    \def\And{%
      \end{tabular}\hfil\linebreak[0]\hfil%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf\rule{\z@}{24\p@}\ignorespaces%
    }
    \def\AND{%
      \end{tabular}\hfil\linebreak[4]\hfil%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf\rule{\z@}{24\p@}\ignorespaces%
    }
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf\rule{\z@}{24\p@}\@author\end{tabular}%
  \vskip 0.4in \@minus 0.1in \center{\today}   \vskip 0.2in
  }
}

% add conference notice to bottom of first page
\newcommand{\ftype@noticebox}{8}
\newcommand{\@notice}{%
  % give a bit of extra room back to authors on first page
  \enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}%
  \@float{noticebox}[b]%
    \footnotesize\@noticestring%
  \end@float%
}

% abstract styling
\renewenvironment{abstract}
{
  \centerline
  {\large \bfseries \scshape Abstract}
  \begin{quote}
}
{
  \end{quote}
}

\endinput
```

**UPDATE 3**:
The whole log in Arxiv:

[Log of Arxiv](https://justpaste.it/434b6)

Comment: arXiv uses some oldish TeX installation, and overleaf also uses an old yet different TeX installation. IMHO if overleaf have a submit to arXiv button, they could really test the file on an installation that resembles the one of arXiv. That is, by using overleaf, you make the problem worse compared to just compiling on your own installation, in which you can at least find out what the versions are used without problems.

Comment: this is exactly the same issue as your question earlier today https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536123/arxiv-not-able-to-process-overleaf-latex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, No this is absolutely not the same as the first question.There I used Biblatex in overleaf and daleif recommended to use bibtex. I exactly did that and removed biblatex and did the steps that was proposed. Now I get the error message I have written here. Thus, I have created a new thread.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I tried to use TexStudio and there I don't get this error message. I don't know what this message means

Comment: well it's basically the same issue that you are using (on arxiv) an older tex system and as you have provided no test example you are relying on someone recognising an internal command in a changed package

Comment: texstudio  isn't relevant that's just the editor.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle says, it is hard to help here. To me there are two black boxes, your code that you do not disclose, and overleaf, as well as a gray box, the arXiv, which is at least transparent in principle. Unless you can provide the relevant parts of your TeX file, your biggest hope is probably that someone shows up who had the same problem and solved it. I personally would *never* use overleaf to prepare a paper that I will submit to the arXiv.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat what kind of information would help you. I mean the paper is more than 35 pages long. I could also provide you Read-Only permissions if you provide me an e-mail address. Otherwise, if you could specify which part I should publish here, I would do that immediatly.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what kind of information would help you. I mean the paper is more than 35 pages long. I could also provide you Read-Only permissions if you provide me an e-mail address. Otherwise, if you could specify which part I should publish here, I would do that immediatly

Comment: the error is on line 95 at begin document so you can make an example that is less than 1 page long.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have updated the content and uploaded it here.

Comment: the error shows begin{document} on line 86 but the sample code doesn't seem to have it on that line, presumably the error is due to subfigure package, but I can't reproduce

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry for that. I have updated it and added arxiv.sty. Now everything should be reproducable.

Comment: @CodePope if I force an error at begin document my terminal output (I used texlive 2017) is nothing like yours many more packages get loaded after `gettitlestring.sty` before begin document is reached:  I will add it to my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a current tex distribution `\sf@counterlist` is defined in `subfig` package (and used in `caption`) package so it (may) work to include those packages in your submission, or to re-write your document not to use those packages.

---

If I run the newly supplied example with texlive2017 (and force an error at begin document) my terminal output is not as you show (note he extra package loading

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./cc752.out) (./cc752.out)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-basic-dicti
onary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-ptm.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msa.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msb.cfg)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.73 \begin{document}\zzz
```

Comment: This is not the problem. I have compressed the document (see UPDATE in the main question) and deleted the package `caption` and everywhere it was used. Package `subfig` wasn't used in my project. But the same error message still appears when uploading to Arxiv.

Comment: @CodePope the ` sf@`... command  is only defined in subfig (and only used in caption) in a current texlive I grepped the input directory, so it is the problem or at least it is equivalent to the problem, you may have local code you have not shown doing the same thing. But since you have so far provided essentially no information, this answer (which already required me to do a search over thousands of files to find uses of that command is probably the best that can be given. At least you should show the _full_ log as the fragment you show does not give the full context for the error.

Comment: I have provided the whole document in the question. As I said please refer to the UPDATE part of my question. There is the whole document which compiles without any error and warning in Overleaf, but fails in Arxiv. The error message in Arxiv is shown there, too. What kind of information do you need yet?

Comment: @CodePope I don't have arxiv.sty and if I remove that the document you provided runs error free in all texlives from 2016 to 2020, but the fragment of the log you show does not seem to match the code you posted

Comment: Sorry for that. I have added arxiv.sty and updated the document and the error message. Now everything should fit

Comment: So what does the error mean that you get and how do I get it away?

Comment: @CodePope sorry you haven't provided a full log and I have given all the help that I can. Have you tried as I suggest here and include the subfigure packge in your upload

Comment: Now, after removing the `subfigure` package, it works on Arxiv. Thank you very much.